# UITableView contentSize not updated after resizing tableHeaderView or tableFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

With the following code:

```
let tableView = ...
let oldSize = tableView.contentSize // header + all rows + footer

tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds.height -= 10

tableView.tableFooterView.bounds.height -= 10
```

you'd see that:

```
assert(tableView.contentSize != oldSize) // ERROR: assertion fails
```

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to re-set `tableHeaderView` or `tableFooterView`:

```
let tableView = ...
let oldSize = tableView.contentSize // header + all rows + footer

tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds.height -= 10
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableView.tableHeaderView

tableView.tableFooterView.bounds.height -= 10
tableView.tableFooterView = tableView.tableFooterView

assert(tableView.contentSize != oldSize) // no error :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableview.reloadData` after you update or set your table header view.